# How can I fix dell mSata SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have been formatting my dell laptop for quite a while, I bought it back in 2012, with one year warranty, it ended last august, but I think since the moment I formatted it to windows 8.1 I probably made some change that fu**ed up my pc.

The computer is Inspiron 15R Special Edition, it contains the following disk setup:

**1 TB HDD + 32 GB SSD(mSata)**

Since I tried to leave windows 8.1, my recently formatted pc is booting in about 6 minutes, which before (dell default) booted in 20 seconds.

I'm having trouble with my SSD mainly since its the booting device it was supposed to be using Intel rapid start technology but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

My SSD once was 32Gb but now its only being recognized as 1Gb!

I have selected Intel Smart Response Technlogy in BIOS:

[image]

Here is my currently Intel RST status tab:

[image]

And when I go to performance tab it shows me this:

[image]

As you can see it recognizes my 32Gb SSD as 1Gb, when its supposed to be working (I have formatted my PC 5 times the last 24 Hours in different ways of booting to see if it will work, and none has worked till now)

Here is my Disk Management tab:

[image]

It shows me an I/O error, I have looked up it in google but don't got any good results.

Here is also my Diskpart:

[image]

OBS: I also tried booting up my PC without O.S just by the USB device with win7 on it, and opened up DOS to see diskpart, I got the same results.

More information:
My DISK 0 had 2 partition (which probably blew up my RAID 0 default configuration, perhaps it made my SSD bad after it), so I restored it to only one.

Comment: What does device manager say about how many drives you have? Usually these types of hybrid SSD and HDD will only look like one drive to the  the computer and the SSD is used for caching transparently (at a very low level) by the drive itself.

Comment: Could you also post model number of your computer, and the drive?

Comment: Model Inspiron 15R SE 7520, my SSD isn't the same driver as my HDD, my SSD name (as it shows on Device Manager): SAMSUNG SATA SSD SCSI Disk Device.

Comment: You may well need to download drivers from the Dell site to get full functionality.  http://www.dell.com/support/my-support/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-se-7520/drivers  Or it could be that the drive has gone bad.

Comment: Well, I have done that, all the 5 times I formatted my PC in the last 24h =/ from the same website.